# Virginia Drivers License suspended while living abroad

Tags: usa, driving-license

I have been living and working in Mexico for three years. I was notified by the Virginia DMV that my drivers license (valid until January 2018) would be suspended because they believe I no longer live in Virginia. I contacted DMV and they said I needed to send them proof of my employment in Mexico. I did so, but received the following reply:

> "Unfortunately, we are unable to process your request at this time. Exceptions are granted if documentation provides evidence of why you are relocated out of state, along with documented proof that you are a residence and still maintain residency in the Commonwealth."

I don't understand how I'm supposed to maintain a valid US drivers license while living out of the country if I don't have an additional residence in the US. Any suggestions or ideas would be very gratefully accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [US driving license when living overseas](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5743/us-driving-license-when-living-overseas)

Comment: @DanGetz this may be a bit different, being notified of a suspension during a period in which a license is valid.

Comment: Things have changed recently since states began to get serious about enforcing the federal RealID regulations; they are much more fussy about proof that you live where you say you do. I'm not sure older answers necessarily apply now.

Comment: You're *not* supposed to maintain a valid US license when you don't reside in the US. You reside in Mexico, so you're supposed to get a Mexican license.

Comment: Actually, [Virginia explicitly allows US citizens working overseas to keep their drivers license](https://www.dmv.virginia.gov/webdoc/pdf/dmv143.pdf). I believe they do this because [Virginians can remain (taxable) "domiciliary residents" when they move overseas](http://www.tax.virginia.gov/content/residency-status) which makes filing tax returns a consequence (and proof) of continued residence. The question for the OP would hence be, have you been filing Virginia income tax returns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to renew a US driver's license when living abroad](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/172/how-to-renew-a-us-drivers-license-when-living-abroad)