# Texas Drivers license, no residence in Texas

Tags: driving-license

I lived in Texas and moved to Germany. I am tired of using the addresses of various friends (who keep moving) for my license. Is there a way to have a Texas drivers license while living abroad with no specific Texas address?

Comment: The answer by David and the duplicate answer all presume you are not a member of the US military and are not married to a military member; the answer is different for the military.

Comment: @GerardAshton You are exactly correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly common question. [This SE page](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5743/us-driving-license-when-living-overseas?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the SE page cited in the "Already Answered" note cover the ground nicely.

In short: states issue drivers license to their residents. States define who's a resident and who's not in different ways. Licenses can often be renewed remotely, although doing so requires being able to receive mail in the state, or having an accommodating friend who'll let you use their address. There doesn't seem to be much (or any) state-level enforcement or investigation of the issue of residency.

The risk is that if it's easily seen that you don't actually live in the state for which you hold a license and therefore don't qualify for it, that someone might find it useful to argue the license isn't valid. You shouldn't have difficulty renting a car, say, but if there's an accident, damage, or civil dispute, insurance coverage on the rental car obtained with this license could be in jeopardy, as well as your ability to claim damages against the driver of another vehicle with which you're involved in an accident.