Can I renew New Jersey drivers license from outside of the US
Can I renew New Jersey drivers license from outside the US

do you live in NJ? Or, at least, can someone receive your mail there?

Can you renew it online? Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5743/us-driving-license-when-living-overseas
